# troubleshooting ipywidgets 8.1.2. not working with jupyter lab 4.1.1

Tags: jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I'm having trouble running ipywidgets 8.1.2 with Jupyter lab 4.1.1. The widget doesn't throw an error, but it just prints the widget as text.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
widgets.IntSlider()
```

Output:

```
IntSlider(value=0)
```

I've tried reinstalling everything, then restarted machine, restarted kernel, tried different browsers, cleared cache, etc.

I've used ipywidgets before on this machine/env but this just isn't happening after recent upgrades to these two packages.

Running Windows 11 Chrome 121.0.6167.185  Firefox 122.0.1 (64-bit)

Any one else come across this?